# Script doesn't exit when function output assigned to a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

A few questions about the sample script below.

I'm calling a function `_foo` and want to capture the output of it into a variable `$bar`, but also use the return status (which may not be `0` or `1`), or failing that have `exit` stop the script (when non-zero).

- Why doesn't the `exit` in function `_foo` work when called this way? (`if ! bar="$(_foo)"`). It works when called "normally".

  - the `exit` will stop the script if I change the if statement to this (but I lose its output): `if ! _foo ; then`
  - the `exit` behaves like `return` and will not stop the script: `if ! bar="$(_foo)" ; then`
  - Just calling a function without the assignment and an exit will work, however calling it like `var="$(func)"` doesn't.
- Is there a better way to capture the output of `_foo` into `$bar` from the function as well as use return status (for other than `0` or `1`, eg a `case` statement?)

I have a feeling I may need to use `trap` somehow.

---

Here's a simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -u
set -o pipefail

_foo() {
    local _retval
    echo "baz" && false
    _retval=$?
    exit ${_retval}
}

echo "start"

if ! bar="$(_foo)" ; then
    echo "foo failed"
else
    echo "foo passed"
fi

echo "${bar}"
echo "end"
```

Here's the ooutput:

```
$ ./foo.sh 
start
foo failed
baz
end
```

---

Here's some more examples:

This will exit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -u
set -o pipefail

func() {
    echo "func"
    exit
}

var=''
func
echo "var is ${var}"
echo "did not exit"
```

This will not exit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -u
set -o pipefail

func() {
    echo "func"
    exit
}

var=''
var="$(func)"
echo "var is ${var}"
echo "did not exit"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`exit` within a function exits the entire script and not just the function (subshells notwithstanding).  To expound:

```
#!/bin/bash
f() {
   exit 3
}
f
exit 0
```

The above script will terminate with exit code 3, while

```
#!/bin/bash
f() {
   exit 3
}
(f)
exit 0
```

will terminate with exit code 0.

The `$(command)` syntax you are using runs `command` within a subshell, and `exit` can only break out as far as the layer that subshell is running *within*.

If you want to capture the exit code and output of something run within a subshell, that is still available to the environment in which the subshell is initiated:

```
#!/bin/bash
subshelloutput="$( echo "output"; exit 3 )"
returnval=$?  # captures subshell's exit code
: more stuff follows
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Is there a way to capture the `exit 3` outside of a subshell? I want both the STDOUT and the RETVAL. I guess with `$?`.

Comment: See expanded answer.

Comment: Thank you. The `set -e` I had was causing it to exit prematurely in the example you gave, but I understand how it's behaving now. For anyone else who ends up here, this link has some good examples of subshells and return statuses: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002

Comment: `set -e` will terminate a script if _anything_ returns a nonzero exit code that isn't immediately caught with an `if` or other conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it another way.

```
_foo () 
{ 
    local _retval
    declare -n output="$1"     # $output is local (by default with declare in a func.)
                               ## and points to $1
    output="baz" && false
    _retval=$?
    echo ${_retval}            # change echo to exit
}
```

Now call `_foo` this way:

```
$ _foo bar
1
$ echo "$bar"
baz
```

When you change `echo` to `exit` in the function definition, the `exit` will exit the script.